# How to implementImage input inside reactstrap dropdown item

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I'm trying to implement a dropdown item that would allow the user to select an image when he clicks on it:

```
  <Dropdown
          isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen}
          toggle={this.toggle}
          direction="left"
        >
          <DropdownToggle
            tag="span"
            onClick={this.toggle}
            data-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-expanded={this.state.dropdownOpen}
            color="danger"
          >
            <span className="badge badge-default w-100 h-100 cursor-pointer-no-color chat-box-button">
              <i className="fa fa-plus cursor-pointer-no-color" />
            </span>
          </DropdownToggle>
          <DropdownMenu className="dropdown-danger scrollable-drop-down-menu">
            <DropdownItem className="lodeep-theme-button drop-down-no-transparent btn-outline-default">
              <label
                htmlFor="avatar-upload"
                style={{
                  cursor: "pointer",
                }}
                title="Change profile image"
              >
                <input
                  id="avatar-upload"
                  type="file"
                  accept="image/*"
                  style={{ display: "none" }}
                  onChange={this.onSelectFile}
                />
                <i className="fa fa-picture-o"></i>
              </label>
            </DropdownItem>
          </DropdownMenu>
        </Dropdown>
```

This is the result:
[image]

The problem is that when I click on the dropdrown item, the dropdown menu closes and nothing happens.  Any idea how to fix this??

---

I added `style={{ display: "none" }}` to keep only the image icon and make the UI look better. If I remove it, I will get a normal input and it would work just fine.
[image]

Comment: Your goal is unclear to say the least. I don't understand your last part of the post: "... Added style and it looks better, removed style and it works just fine..." what's the issue there?

Comment: Do you want the `display`'s value to be dynamic?